# Excel web api custom property retrieval fails for saved workbook

Tags: excel, office-js

Using Excel Version 1803 (Build 912xxxxx) when I try to fetch a custom property for 
a workbook which has been saved the excel application hangs. The same code snippet works fine if the excel workbook is in an unsaved state. I have tested the below snippet in scriptlab

```
    var customDocProps = context.workbook.properties.custom;
    console.log("Proceeding to load custom properties");
    context.load(customDocProps);
    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Proceeding to evaluate execute context results");
            var docidprop = customDocProps.getItemOrNullObject("abc");
            context.load(docidprop);
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    if (typeof (docidprop.value) === 'undefined') {
                        console.log("No such custom property");
                    }
                });
        });
```

I also noticed that when this code fires on a saved workbook the memory usage of the Excel application peaks up and I have to kill the excel application process

Answer (score 0):

As per the [office dev team](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/234#issuecomment-418232479) this is a bug in excel and has been fixed and will be rolled out shortly.